# Attempt to de-reference a null object when throwing a custom exception

Tags: apex, exception

I have created a custom Exception class

```
public class StatusException extends Exception{};
```

when using it to throw an error it's throwing a null pointer exception too.

```apex
public class ContainerSync2 {
    public virtual class BaseException extends Exception {}
    
    public static Integer noOfRecordsProcessed=0;
    
    @InvocableMethod(label='Do Sync' description='To Start the Campaign Container Sync.')
    public static void doSync(){
        ContainerSync2.sync();
    }
    
    public static void sync(){
        List<String> errors=new List<String>();
        String errorResponse='';
        try{
            List<Campaign> campaignsToCreate=new List<Campaign>();
            String recordTypeId=Schema.SObjectType.Campaign.getRecordTypeInfosByName().get('Status IO Campaign').getRecordTypeId();
            List<Campaign> campaignList=[SELECT Id, Name, Status_IO_Component_Ids__c, Status_IO_Id__c, Type FROM Campaign WHERE Status_IO_Id__c != null];
            Map<String,Campaign> statusIoIdMAp=new Map<String,Campaign>();
            for(Campaign cmp:campaignList){
                statusIoIdMAp.put(cmp.Status_IO_Id__c,cmp);    
            }
        
            Http http=new Http();
            HttpRequest req=new HttpRequest();
            req.setEndpoint(myEndPoint);
            req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
            req.setMethod('GET');
            req.setHeader('x-api-id', API_Id);
            req.setHeader('x-api-key', API_key);
         
            HttpResponse res=http.send(req);
            if(res.getStatus()=='OK'){
                //API successfull
                String apiResponse=res.getBody();
                apiResponse=apiResponse.replaceAll('_id', 'id');
                StatusIOjson obj=StatusIOjson.parse(apiResponse);
                system.debug(obj);
                if(obj.status.error=='yes') {
                    throw new BaseException('Sync Failed.');
                }
                noOfRecordsProcessed=obj.result.size();
                for(StatusIOjson.cls_result tmp:obj.result){
                    Campaign currentCampaign=statusIoIdMAp.get(tmp.id);
                    String addedContainerIds='';
                    for(StatusIOjson.cls_containers container:tmp.containers){
                        addedContainerIds=addedContainerIds+container.id+',';
                    }
                    addedContainerIds = addedContainerIds.removeEnd(',');
                    if(currentCampaign==null){
                        Campaign newCampaignToCreate=new Campaign();
                        newCampaignToCreate.Name=tmp.name;
                        newCampaignToCreate.Status_IO_Id__c=tmp.id;
                         newCampaignToCreate.Status_IO_Component_Ids__c=addedContainerIds;
                        newCampaignToCreate.Type='Status IO';
                        newCampaignToCreate.RecordTypeId=recordTypeId;
                        campaignsToCreate.add(newCampaignToCreate);
                    }else{
                        currentCampaign.Name=tmp.name;
                         currentCampaign.Status_IO_Component_Ids__c=addedContainerIds;
                    }
                }
                     
                //insert and update.
                insert campaignsToCreate;
                update statusIoIdMAp.values();
                     
            }/*else{
                //API failed.
                errorResponse=res.getBody();
            }  */ 
                 
        }catch(Exception e){
            errors.add(e.getMessage());
            System.debug(e.getCause());
            System.debug(e.getLineNumber());
            System.debug(e.getMessage());
        }finally{
            //use errors and send the email.
            List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emailList = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
            List<String> address = new List<String>{'mridul.kapil@test.com'};
            
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            mail.setToAddresses(address);
            emailList.add(mail);
            if(errors.size()==0){
                mail.setSubject('Container Campaign Sync Successful');
                mail.setHtmlBody('Hi, <p>'+noOfRecordsProcessed+ ' Containers have been synced with Campaigns successfully.</p>');
            }else{
                mail.setSubject('Container Campaign Sync Failed');
                errors.remove(null);
                mail.setHtmlBody('Hi, <p> Containers sync failed. '+string.join(errors,',')+'</p>');
            }
        
            if(!emailList.isEmpty()){
                Messaging.sendEmail(emailList);
            }      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Mridul, can you post the logs you are getting? (including what line the NPE is being thrown)

Comment: it's saying null in the cause at line number 40 which is "      throw new BaseException('Sync Failed.'); "

Comment: could you update your question including all code in the method you are calling? I just tested your code, as is in your question, and got no error. so it might be somewhere else.

Comment: added the whole class

Comment: my guess is that `obj.status.error` is the one causing the NPE. add a `System.debug(obj.status)` right before the `if` statement and post its outcome.

Comment: it has a string I checked that. When I'm commenting on the throw statement or even throwing without any message it's still throwing an error

Comment: have you try commenting out/removing the `throw new BaseException('Sync Failed.');` line? do you still get the error?

Comment: It worked, it was because of "errors.remove(null);" so when I removed it started working as expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removing `errors.remove(null);` worked for me.